# How to get the json data from the url using Python script apart from requests library?

Tags: python, json, parsing, ubuntu, python-requests

I have a URL which gives me the below JSON String if I hit them on the browser -

Below is my URL, let's say it is `URL-A` and I have around three URL's -

```
http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
```

And below is my JSON String -

```
{
 "description": "",
 "statistics": {
  "dataCount": 0,
 }
}
```

Now I have written a Python script which is scanning all my 3 URL's and then parse then JSON String to extract the value of `dataCount` from it. And it should keep on running every few seconds to scan the URL and then parse it.

Below are my URL's

```
hostnameA       http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
hostnameB       http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
hostnameC       http://hostnameC:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
```

And the data I want to see is like this on the console, here `dataCount` will be actual number

```
hostnameA - dataCount
hostnameB - dataCount
hostnameC - dataCount
```

And I have the below python script which works fine locally on my cygwin but if I am running it on my company's production ubuntu machine it gives an error -

```
import requests
from time import sleep

def get_data_count(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return 'could not get page'

    try:
        # this line is giving an error
        return int(req.json['statistics']['dataCount'])
    except TypeError:
        return 'field not found'
    except ValueError:
        return 'not an integer'

def main():
    urls = [
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameB', 'http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameC', 'http://hostnameC:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json')
    ]

    while True:
        print('')
        for name, url in urls:
            res = get_data_count(url)
            print('{name} - {res}'.format(name=name, res=res))
        sleep(10.)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Below is the error I am getting -

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'
```

I am using Python 2.7.3 and Ubuntu 12.04 and the version of `requests` I am running is `0.8.2` (I guess this is the problem).

In any case, is there any way I can rewrite the above script using some other library apart from `requests` meaning just the portion of getting the data from server, we can use other libraries right?

Since I guess, I cannot update this package since it's our production ubuntu servers so I need to find some other way to do this.

Comment: Indeed, `requests` 0.8.2 is ancient and does not support `.json`. You can install a *newer* version in a virtualenv, which will then be used instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, but how do I install `virutualenv`? I have never use it before. If  you can guide me then it will be of great help. Not a python expert :(

Comment: There is a [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-virtualenv); that's for Precise Pangolin, the Ubuntu version of your server (judging by the 0.8.2 version tag of `requests`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `requests` still, just not rely on the response object to do the decoding for you:

```
import json

# ...
data = json.loads(req.content)
return int(data['statistics']['dataCount'])
```

Version 0.8.2 is ancient; you can use `virtualenv` to create a location for you to install a newer version instead:

```
$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing Setuptools..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing Pip.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
$ cd venv/
$ bin/pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-2.2.1.tar.gz (421kB): 421kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

Installing collected packages: requests
  Running setup.py install for requests

Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
$ bin/python -c 'import requests; print requests.__version__'
2.2.1
```

Comment: And thanks for letting me know how to use `virtualenv`.